# How do I manage when to use external battery in a dual-battery laptop?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I have a Lenovo X270 laptop which has two batteries; one internal and one external. I tried installing Ubuntu 18 and the first battery was being drained to 0% and then the external battery was being used.

**Current Behaviour**

1. Internal battery reaches 0% charge.
2. The laptop shuts down.
3. After rebooting, the laptop then begins to use the external battery.

Not only is this going to ruin the internal battery, it's not ideal to have to reboot every time.

**Desired Behaviour (Currently how Windows 10 handles it)**

1. Internal battery reaches 20% charge.
2. The laptop automatically fails over to the external battery without interruption.

I've found plenty of examples of how to do the inverse (prevent charging above a certain threshold) but nothing to limit discharging.